# Number of Records in Insert Statement (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, insert, numbers, records

I'd like to report on the number of records inserted in an Oracle insert statement.  I'm inserting from a statement, so I could run my select twice and a count, but I'd rather keep it all in a single statement.  Is there a way?

Comment: Please tell more about the programming language and the environment.

Comment: I work in both PL/SQL and .Net, so both your answers are relivant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Doing an INSERT in PL/SQL `SQL%ROWCOUNT` gives the number of inserted rows.

Doing an INSERT in C# `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of inserted rows.